# AndroidWear - Can't send many notifications at the same time to smartwatch

Tags: android, notifications, watch, sony-smartwatch

My app detects if the user's location is close to the shop.If so it sends  notifications containing shop's coupons. Unfortunately,this way too many notifications are send to the smartwatch at the same time. This forces me to restart my watch. Does anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

What is the rate you are sending notifications to the SmartWatch? Maybe you should use geofencing if you are not already.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html